# NullPointerException when connecting Confluent Kafka and InfluxDB

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to use the Confluent [InfluxDB Sink Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-influxdb/) to get data from a kafka topic into my InfluxDB.

Firstly, I transmit data to kafka topic from a log file by using nifi, and it works well. The kafka topic get the data, like below:

```
  {
    "topic": "testDB5",
    "key": null,
    "value": {
      "timestamp": "2019-03-20 01:24:29,461",
      "measurement": "INFO",
      "thread": "NiFi Web Server-795",
      "class": "org.apache.nifi.web.filter.RequestLogger",
      "message": "Attempting request for (anonymous) 
    },
    "partition": 0,
    "offset": 0
  }
```

Then, I create InfluxDB sink connector through the Kafka Connect UI , and I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:587)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:323)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:194)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.confluent.influxdb.InfluxDBSinkTask.put(InfluxDBSinkTask.java:140)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:565)
    ... 10 more
```

But if I manually input data to another topic testDB1 by using

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic testDB1 --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"measurement","type":"string"},{"name":"timestamp","type":"string"}]}'
```

It works, my influxDB can get the data.

Here is the connect configuration:

```
connector.class=io.confluent.influxdb.InfluxDBSinkConnector
influxdb.url=http://myurl
tasks.max=1
topics=testDB5
```

the configuration of connecting topic testDB1 is the same except topics name.

Is there any problems in nifi ? But it can transmit data to topic well.

Comment: How are you serialising the data that you write to the Kafka topic? What serialiser (`converter`) settings are you using in your Kafka Connect worker properties file?

Comment: in etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties, the setting is: `key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081`

Comment: How are you serialising the data that you write to the Kafka topic?

Comment: In nifi flow, i use GrokReader to read the log file, and then use AvroRecordSetWriter to write into the kafka topic,  you can click the link again for more detail [link](https://blog.csdn.net/Waves___/article/details/88659317)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. It's because in Nifi, I used `PublishKafka_0_10` to publish the data to Kafka topic, but its version is to low!

When I make a query in ksql, it says that

```
Input record ConsumerRecord(..data..) has invalid (negative) timestamp.
Possibly because a pre-0.10 producer client was used to write this record to Kafka without embedding a timestamp, 
or because the input topic was created before upgrading the Kafka cluster to 0.10+. Use a different TimestampExtractor to process this data.
```

So, I change it to `PublishKafka_1_0` , and start again, and it works! My influxDB can get the data. I'm speechless.

And thanks Robin Moffatt for the reply, its very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Avro with Kafka Connect, the Avro deserialiser expects the data to have been serialised using the [Avro serialiser](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#serializer). This is what the `kafak-avro-console-producer` uses, which is why your pipeline works when you use that.

[This article](https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-avro-serialization-and-the-schema-registry) gives a good background to Avro and the Schema Registry. See also [Kafka Connect Deep Dive – Converters and Serialization Explained](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained).

I'm not familiar with Nifi, but looking at the documentation it seems that [AvroRecordSetWriter](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.avro.AvroRecordSetWriter/index.html) has the option to use [Confluent Schema Registry](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-confluent-platform-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.confluent.schemaregistry.ConfluentSchemaRegistry/index.html). At a guess you'll also want to set `Schema Write Strategy` to `Confluent Schema Registry Reference`.

Once you can consume data from your topic with `kafka-avro-console-consumer` then you know that it is correctly serialised and will work with your Kafka Connect sink.

Comment: Actually, using the schema registry is not mandatory to write to Kafka, so I would suggest he would actually use the `Embed Avro Schema` option which would not require him to provide any schema.

Comment: It's not mandatory, unless you want to _deserialise the Avro data using Kafka Connect with the default Avro deserialiser_. So yes you can put whatever you want onto the Kafka topic, but if you want it to be readable by a consumer the other end you have to use the same serialiser/deserialiser. In this case Kafka Connect is configured to use the Schema Registry Avro deserialiser and thus for the messages to be processed they need to be placed on the Kafka topic using the Schema Registry Avro serialiser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried again just now, and while the data were transmitted to the Kafka topic by Nifi, the data could be consumed with  `kafka-avro-console-consumer` ! But the logs still have that exception `java.lang.NullPointerException`, and my influxDB could not get the data.

Comment: Yes, I have already set `Schema Write Strategy` to `Confluent Schema Registry Reference`.

Comment: So if you write to a new topic, using the new config, can you consume every message from that topic using `kafka-avro-console-consumer`? And the Connector still fails with the same error? If so, what does the data on the topic look like after deserialisation ?

Comment: Yes, every message can be consumed with `kafka-avro-console-consumer`, and the connector still fails with `java.lang.NullPointerException`. The data on the topic is the same as the log file.